# Listening to all form submit events

Tags: javascript, jquery

jQuery's `on('submit', ...)` correctly picks up native form submits i.e. when the submit button is pressed, however it doesn't play well with JS form submits, at least on FF&IE

With that in mind, how would one go about adding submit listeners "properly"? Modifying DOM prototype by changing the behaviour of `HTMLFormElement.prototype.submit` doesn't work on IE7

[fiddled](http://jsfiddle.net/ovfiddle/5VXcz/)

Comment: There's a very good reason why the native js `.submit()` doesn't trigger the onsubmit handler - namely that you could (and often would) very easily form an endless recursion of submit-handler-submit-handler-submit.... If you need to run a form's handler from js then use eg `$("#myform").trigger('submit')`.

Comment: @Beetroot-Beetroot: oh, that's kind of obvious now that you've mentioned it :) thanks, that makes sense

Comment: Depending on what you are trying to do, you can sometimes catch `window.onpageunload` to do some basic cleanup.

Comment: @JeremyJStarcher: I'm trying adding some data to the form prior to submission - wouldn't really work with `onpageunload` and its cross-browser support is a bit quirky anyway

Answer (score 0):

Using the jQuery `.submit()` to submit your form will take care of the problem.

```
$('#someForm').submit();
```

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5VXcz/4/)

Of course it won't help much if you really insist on using the native DOM `.submit()`.