# Pausing a form submission in Javascript or jQuery, no matter what method

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, events, submit

I am building a frontend Javascript library that needs to be able to work on all manners of websites that install it.  One of the functions will be to intercept a form submission, send some data back to the server, and then continue the form submission.

Thing is, form submissions can work in different ways.  If someone is using a normal HTML form or the "submit" listener, that's all good, but if someone is doing something fancy like submitting the form using the enter key, or running a submit function on button click, I need to be able to pick up those submission events as well.  It's also possible to "submit" a form by just sending the serialized form data to the server without submitting the HTML form.

Is there a plugin or some way to detect all manners in which someone might submit form data, and intercept it to run my script, then resume it again?

Comment: You cannot take care of all possible ways of sending data to the server.

Comment: You may have to provide an ajax based API that the user has to use for all submits.

Comment: I assume [there is no way](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15260974/listening-to-all-form-submit-events) :\